# add contents of table to a select box with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table which is generated at the bottom of my page.  I want to get the contents of that table (the second column) and put it in a select box at the top of my page.  Ideally in alphabetical order.

I am short on ideas here but this is the code I currently have.

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Lots of content goes here...</p>
    <p>Lots of content goes here...</p>
    <p>Lots of content goes here...</p>
    <p>Lots of content goes here...</p>
    <p>Lots of content goes here...</p>
    <table id="fav-table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.example/com/durham">Durham</a></td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.example/com/leicester">Leicester</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.example/com/london">London</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.example/com/manchester">Manchester</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td><td><a href="http://www.example/com/worcester">Worcester</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.example/com/newcastle">Newcastle</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

With the jquery

```
    jQuery('#content').prepend(jQuery('#fav-table').html());
```

If I manually add this jquery then it works.

```
jQuery('#content').prepend('<select><option value="http://www.example/com/durham">Durham</option><option value="http://www.example/com/leicester">Leicester</option><option value="http://www.example/com/london">London</option><option value="http://www.example/com/manchester">Manchester</option><option value="http://www.example/com/newcastle">Newcastle</option><option value="http://www.example/com/worcester">Worcester</option></select>');
```

However as the table's data may change I want the jquery to be based on the second column of the table.
How would I go about doing this?

I have put the code in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/jVKe3/) as well.

Comment: What makes you think that you can  append a table to a select element?

Comment: what he did mean is convert it to select , and it is pretty clear

Comment: @codeiz Where do you see _convert_ word in the question? In this line `jQuery('#content').prepend(jQuery('#fav-table').html());`?

Comment: "I want to get the contents of that table (the second column) and put it in a select box at the top of my page. Ideally in alphabetical order. " isnt that clear enough for you plus there is two answers , so dont blame me , it's you the one who didnt get it

Comment: @codeiz I appreciate your effort for answering the question and I know what he wants, the point was something else.

Comment: i know that you would like that ppl try before posting or even understand what they are doing , but i think that if you help somebody he will understand it better and faster than  him pulling out his hair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated :

```
 $('body').append('<select id="select">');
     var mylist = $('#select');
    $('#fav-table tr td:nth-child(2) a').each(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
        mylist.append('<option value=' + $(this).attr('href') + '>'+text+'</option>')
    }
    )


     var listitems = mylist.children('option').get();
     listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
        var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
        var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
        return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
     })
     $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

the order code was taken from other question 
[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5GU7r/1/)

Comment: This is great thanks. Except the values of each option don't seem to come accross?  Also the alphabetical order is great but one thing I can't work out from what you have done is why is durham always selected by default?  Eg if you change manchester to amanchester it appears at the top of the select box but durham still seems to be selected?

Comment: no that's not right , i have tried to add other row and the selected option is the first option (which is the defualt ); i have updated my answer to include the value which is the href attribute of the anchor tag

Comment: Ok thanks that works exactly how I had hoped now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: with that issue I was mentioning about the first row of the table being the default in the select box. I have loooked at it in firefox and it seems that the issue only exists here.  Do you get the same thing? eg i nfirefox durham is selected on load?

Comment: nope ...! it is working good .. if your getting the table from php then just order the result alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

Try this it might help. Change to suit your need  :)

```
var values=[], options=[];

//Iterate  td's in second column
$('#fav-table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2)').each( function(){
//add item to array
values.push( $(this).text() );         
});

//restrict array to unique items so that select have only unique values in dropdown
var values = $.unique( values );

var values = values.sort();// sort the array

//iterate unique array and build array of select options
$.each( values, function(i, value){
options.push('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>'); 
})

//finally empty the select and append the items from the array
$('#selectId').empty().append( options.join() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `select` object add `options` to it before adding to your `div` as you are doing by creating html string of select and adding it. You can use jQuery `sort` to sort the anchor text and then `each` to iterate through for creating options.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/jVKe3/6/)**

```
sel = $('<select>');
jQuery('#fav-table a').sort(function(a, b){
    return $(a).text() > $(b).text();
}).each(function () {
  sel.append("<option value=\"" + this.href + "\">" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
});
jQuery('#content').prepend(sel);
```

Comment: seems yo work well thanks for other people viewing the answer the live demo link seems to link back to my original fiddle?

Comment: I have added the sort as well, have a look.

Comment: Thanks the sort doesn't seem 100% alphabetical order but it gives me something to work with!

Comment: You may need to be specify in sort, now I used text().